# How to run partimage after installation on Ubuntu 12.04 if it is not listed in Dash?

Tags: software-installation, unity-dash

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual boot laptop with Windows Vista.

I installed `partimage` through the Software Centre and it says that the package is successfully installed, but the package is not shown in the list of installed software through Dash.

What can I do to get Dash to show partimage as an installed package?

If I can't get Dash to list the package, is there another way to run partimage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if PartImage isn't in the Dash it can still be run. Open a Terminal and run PartImage from there:

```
partimage
```

The program should run.

Comment: Thanks japzone for your answer BUT I will be more comfortable with GUI.  How can I do that?

Comment: I tried it from terminal and GUI opens.  Thanks japzone.But I would be glad to know the reason why it is not showing in dash

Comment: I'll update my Answer with a guide to adding it to the Dash in a bit. I'm busy with some things at the moment.